# Jssor slider - adding hyperlinks

Tags: jssor

Does anyone know if it's possible for each slide in the slider control to link to a URL when clicked on?

The control has been great for me so far, but a customer has asked for the above and I can't see an obvious way of doing it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use following code to define a slide with link.

```
<div><a u="image" href="url"><img src="image.jpg" /></a></div>
```

Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/define-slides-html-code.html

Comment: Brilliant - thanks! Didn't see that in the documentation for some reason!